# How to throw an SQL Exception back to the calling asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I currently have an ASP.NET application that handles all calls to the database through stored procedures and we handle all SQL transactions application side.

My problem is that I need to throw an exception in my Stored Procedure so it can be caught in the Application and the transaction can be rolled back. I have currently tried RAISERROR and THROW but they only return messages and don't actual cause an exception.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: RAISEERROR should do it. Check your code maybe you're suppressing the exception somewhere.

Comment: Both `RAISEERROR` and `THROW` should generate a `SQLException` unless it's handled with a `TRY..CATCH` in the SQL.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The severity level of a `RAISERROR()` call in your stored procedure must be greater than or equal to 16 in order to generate a `SqlException` on the calling side. Here is an example of a `RAISERROR()` that will generate a `SqlException`:

```
RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.
           16, -- Severity.
           1 -- State.
           );
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I was using a Severity level greater then 16. Turns out there was a hidden try catch in the application that wasn't including the parameter that causes the error. So the RAISERROR was never called.

Comment: 0-10  Indicates informational messages and not actual errors,
11-16 Indicate errors that can be corrected by the user,
17-19 Indicate software errors that cannot be corrected by the user,
20-24 Indicate system problems and are fatal errors